# Flutter Foreground Darwin Notification not Showing in iOS Notification Center

Tags: ios, flutter

I have implemented a notification system in my app, and it is working as expected however, the notifications in the foreground are not saving in my iOS (16.6.1) Notification Center.

below is my code:

````
    // Display a notification using flutter_local_notifications
    final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = 
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'your_channel_id', // Replace with your channel ID
            'Default Channel',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            showWhen: true,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground',
            autoCancel: false,
    );

    final DarwinNotificationDetails iosPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      DarwinNotificationDetails(
         presentSound: true, 
        presentAlert: true, 
        badgeNumber: null, 
        presentBanner: true,

      );


    final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iosPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    try {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, // Notification ID
        message.notification?.title ?? '',
        message.notification?.body ?? '',
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error displaying notification: ${e}');
    }
  }```

the background notifications are Displayed in my iOS Notification Center though, why is the foreground Notification not Displaying.
````